# Python list comprehension with if statement inside two for loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following python code:

```
result = [{k:str(row[k]) for k in row.keys()}  for row in rows]
```

Now I want to add conditions like this: 
if k != 'count': add to the list
else: do not add to list.

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify with inputs and expected and actual outputs.

Comment: If you're working with a database, you'd best do this directly in the DB query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have fewer lookups if you iterate over items. Assuming all keys are strings, the `if` is easy:

```
result = [{k:str(v) for k,v in row.items() if k != 'count'}  for row in rows]
```

...or if you want to only add things that don't have counts

```
result = [row.copy()  for row in rows if 'count' not in row]
```